# Computing Fourier Transform for $(1 - e^{-iyx})\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}$

Tags: functions, fourier-transform

I have to compute Fourier Transform for the function $(1 - e^{-iyx})\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}$ where $y > 0, 0.5 < \alpha < 1.5$.

My attempt: I have to compute the following integral $$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{itx}(1 - e^{-iyx})\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}\, dx$$ I tried to use complex integration to deal with this problem. Firstly, let's assume t < 0, so we can consider contour $K_1$ in lower-half plane consisted of two segments $(-R, -\epsilon)$ and $(\epsilon, R)$, and two semicircles $C_{\epsilon}, C_R$ with center at $z=0$ and radius $\epsilon, R$ as well. So we have $$I_{K_1} = \int_{K_1} e^{itx}(1 - e^{-iyx})\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}} = 0,$$ as there are no singularities inside $K_1$. We can prove that

$$
\int_{C_R} e^{itx}(1 - e^{-iyx})\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}} \rightarrow 0, R \rightarrow \infty, \qquad \qquad \int_{C_\epsilon} e^{itx}(1 - e^{-iyx})\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}} \rightarrow 0, \epsilon \rightarrow 0,
$$
so we have that $I = 0$ for $t < 0$. But it seems that we can use the same principe for t > 0, but in upper half plane. However it seems to be completely wrong. I guess it's because of branch cuts of $ \frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}$, but I don't know how to deal with it.

Need your help to finish this problem!

Comment: Mathematica gives the result $$\mathcal{F}_x\left[\left(1-e^{-i x y}\right)\, x^{-\alpha}\right](t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(1-e^{-i x y}\right)\, x^{-\alpha}\, e^{i t x} \, dx\\=e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \pi \alpha} \sin(\pi \alpha)\, \Gamma(1-\alpha) \left((\text{sgn}(t-y)-1) |t-y|^{\alpha-1}-(\text{sgn}(t)-1)|t|^{\alpha-1}\right)\tag{1}$$ which is valid for $y\in\mathbb{R}\land 0<\Re(\alpha)<1$ if you're interested, but I don't know how Mathematica derives derives this result.

Comment: @StevenClark thank you for the answer, but I need to derive this result analytically. Maybe it'll be a bit easier with this formula

Comment: What means $x^\alpha$ in your question?

Comment: @LL3.14 standard definition is $x^{\alpha} = e^{\alpha Log(x)}$, where $Log$ - complex logarithm

Comment: So I suppose you mean the principal branch? $\ln(x) = \ln(|x|) +i\pi$ for negative $x$? That means $x^\alpha = |x|^\alpha\,e^{i\pi \,\alpha}$? It might help because I think the Fourier transform of functions of the form $|x|^c\,\mathbf{1}_{x>0}$ is known. Also, you write "I have to compute" ... what is the context?

Comment: @LL3.14 it's good idea, thank you, I'll try it. I'm working on the problem of integral representations of some stochastic processes and this integral appears during the solution. But it can be viewed as separate interesting problem